# How to install Xamarin on Windows using Chef

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, chef-infra, windows-server-2012

I configure my TeamCity build agents (Windows Server 2012 VMs) using Chef, and I have a need to install Xamarin for an Visual Studio/Android build. For other installers I usually play around with invoking it with `/h`, `/help`, `/?`, `-?`, `-h` and `--help` until I get a usage dialog that tells me the command-line parameters. I have not been able to figure out the command-line parameters for the `XamarinInstaller.exe`, however, and when I launch it like this:

```
XamarinInstaller.exe /quiet /norestart
```

since those are common conventions, it seems that it just sits there and doesn't do anything. It should be downloaded stuff (that's what it does when I launch it with the GUI) but when I look at the Ethernet usage in the task manager, nothing much is happening. I don't know where it writes it logs or how to know if it has failed. It doesn't seem to quit when it has failed.

Here is my Chef code:

```rb
xamarinTargets = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\Xamarin\\Android\\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets'

xamarinInstaller = 'C:\\Repo\\Xamarin\\XamarinInstaller.exe'

execute "Xamarin" do
  command "#{xamarinInstaller} /quiet /norestart"
  not_if { ::File.exist?(xamarinTargets) }
end
```

How do I invoke the Xamarin installer headlessly? How do I install it with Chef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I had to do, and some of it is kind of wonky.

1. Install `android-sdk` and `xamarin-visualstudio` via Chocolatey using the `chocolatey_package` resource from the `chocolatey` cookbook.
2. Verify the Xamarin install worked as expected.
3. Unzip a prefabbed `android-sdk.zip` into `$HOME\AppData\Local\Android` in order to get everything I need installed in the Android SDK*
4. Verify the Android SDK install worked as expected.
5. Create a registry key to point Xamarin's Visual Studio integration to the appropriate Android SDK.

Here it is in Chef code:

```rb
xamarinTargets = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\Xamarin\\Android\\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets'

chocolatey_package 'android-sdk'
chocolatey_package 'xamarin-visualstudio'

ruby_block "Verify Xamarin MSBuild targets exist" do
    block do
        if not ::File.exist?(xamarinTargets)
            raise "Did not find #{xamarinTargets} which was supposed to have been created by the Xamarin install"
        end
    end
end

homeDir = "C:\\Users\\#{ENV['User']}"
androidDir = "#{homeDir}\\AppData\\Local\\Android"
androidSdk = "#{androidDir}\\android-sdk"
androidSdkZip = "C:\\Repo\\Android\\android-sdk.zip"
adbExe = "#{androidSdk}\\platform-tools\\adb.exe"

seven_zip_archive "Android SDK API level 15" do
    path androidDir
    source androidSdkZip
    overwrite true
    not_if { ::File.exist?(adbExe) }
end

ruby_block "Verify Android adb.exe exists" do
    block do
        if not ::File.exist?(adbExe)
            raise "Did not find #{adbExe} which was supposed to have been created by the Android SDK install"
        end
    end
end

registry_key 'HKEY_USERS\\S-1-5-18\\Software\\Novell\\Mono\ for\ Android' do
  values [{
    :name => "AndroidSdkDirectory",
    :type => :string,
    :data => androidSdk
  }]
  recursive true
  action :create
end
```

---

*I could not for the life of me get `android update sdk` to work when invoked through Chef. It seems that the Android SDK Manager won't run even nongraphically unless it can detect that it is being run by a user?! Not sure, but finally in desperation, I ran the command manually to install the necessary SDK (I need API level 15) and build tools:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools,platform-tools,build-tools-23.0.3,android-15"
```

I then took the resulting `$HOME\AppData\Local\Android\android-sk` directory and zipped it to produce the "prefabbed `android-sdk.zip`" mentioned above.